# ConstraintMatchTotal how to get weight and score level?

Tags: optaplanner

Since OptaPlanner 7.0.0.Beta7 the ConstraintMatchTotal class no longer has a score level or a value for its total weight. What is a good way to get those values for each ConstraintMatchTotal object?

I know that ConstraintMatchTotal now returns a Score object but the only way to get the information I need seems to be to traverse the toLevelNumbers array until I find the first non-zero value. This seems inefficient and cumbersome. Is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `score.toShortString()`.

Why do you need the weight?

- If you need it to do calculations, just calculate with the `Score` objects, that also has `add()`, `subtract()` etc.
- If you need it to display to the user, use `toShortString()`, it will turn `0hard/0medium/-5soft` into simply `-5soft`.

[See also the code example in the upgrade recipe to 7.](https://www.optaplanner.org/download/upgradeRecipe/upgradeRecipe7.0.html)

Comment: I saw the change in the Upgrade Recipe but I still need to support my existing API.

That means I still need to get the score level value (I am using a BendableScore) and the weight as an integer. Any chance that these can be brought back?

Comment: A score rule that affects 2 score levels, for example medium and soft, will now have only one ConstraintMatch (this was a needed change for the indictment heat maps to work). How would you envision those API methods to look like? Feel free to create a jira with some strawman examples on how to bring those methods back accordingly.